# Register_block_style() and performances :'(

Tags: wordpress

I've added some styles for one of my blocks but I have issue with bad performances because of the preview ! Does Anyone know how I could disable this preview ?
If I remove this code in block-editor.js it works but this not the good way of doing it:

```js
Object(external_wp_element_["createElement"])("div", {
    className: "block-editor-block-styles__item-preview"
  }, Object(external_wp_element_["createElement"])(block_preview, {
    viewportWidth: 500,
    blocks: previewBlocks
  }))
```

Please help me !
Thanks